# What does this question mean (Taylor series and Newton-Raphson methpd)?

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion, roots, newton-raphson

This is a question about proving the Newton Raphson formula (I think!), and I'm not quite sure what it is asking for. I would rather I wasn't told the answer as I would like to figure it out myself, unless of course it is difficult to explain what the question means without answering it!

> > "Write down the Taylor series for a function f evaluated at x+h in terms of f(x) and its derivatives evaluated at x"

Specifically,

1.Does this mean the expansion of f(x) about x=-h (so that terms are (x+h)?

2.Or perhaps the expansion of f(x+h) about x? At the moment, I think it seems most likely that they are asking for this, however I would then think that the derivatives would be evaluated at (-x), as they are evaluated at (a) for an expansion of f(x-a)...

Comment: Taylor expansion about $x$. The powers are $\bigl((x+h) - x\bigr)^k = h^k$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you for your reply! So am I correct in thinking that the 'h' term is like the x in a normal Taylor expansion about x=a, so in this question they are looking for:     $f(x+h)=f(x)+f'(x)h+\frac{1}{2}f''(x)h^2+...$

Comment: That's right. In the form $f(y) = f(a) + f'(a)(y-a) + \frac{1}{2} f''(a)(y-a)^2 +\dotsc$, $a = x$ and $y = x+h$.